# Second bluetooth device paired, trusted and connected but doesnt work

Tags: bluetooth

I connect the bluetooth keyboard and its working fine, then I connect the bluetooth headphones and its paired, trusted and connected but doesn't work.
If I connect first the heaphones, they work perfectly, then I connect the keyboard and keyboard doesn't work, it's always the second device that pair, trust and connect but doesn't work. I am using xubuntu, any thoughts?

`sudo systemctl status bluetooth`

[image: Screenshot]

"sim" means "yes" and "não" means "no"

[image: blueman screenshot]

Comment: Unless your Bluetooth device (and likely the peripherals as well) is v.5.x then you can't have more than one working.

Comment: @ChanganAuto my device is v4 and I can use a bluetooth mouse and headset at the same time

Comment: @Jeremy31 News to me but admittedly I never tried, just accepted this piece of "common wisdom"

Comment: Had made a "sudo hciconfig -a" and between other information had this two lines " HCI Version: 4.0 (0x6)  Revision: 0xe2f   \n   LMP Version: 4.0 (0x6)  Subversion: 0x9f73  ", So after so many tries to make this work, I suppose its not possible, because my bluetooth device is v4.  Thanks for the info  ChanganAuto and Jeremy31.